# Passing column name in knex.stream

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe, knex.js

I'm currently using knex to query my database and stream the results into a CSV file uploaded on s3.

However, I'm struggling to find a way to pass the column names so they constitute the first row of my csv file.

Here is my code:

```
const stringifier = Stringify()    
knex.raw('SELECT id, name FROM table LIMIT 20').stream().pipe(stringifier)
                .pipe(gzip)
                .pipe(s3WritableStream);
```

This only send each row.

What should I do to have the name of each column included as the first row in the CSV?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.
Just add "header" to stringify:

```
const stringifier = Stringify({
                header:true
            })
```